# Remote control / inspect existing GTK application

Tags: widget, gtk, ui-automation, gtk3, gtk2

How can I **non-interactively** access the widget tree of an existing GTK application? I'd like to query the coordinates of a widget, and if possible send events (hover, click, key press, …).

Using GTKInspector, I can do browse the widget tree interactively and see the size and coordinates of a widget. I'd like to access this info using a command-line tool, or using some GTK API in any language.

[image: Screenshot of mate-calc with GTKInspector in the background.]

```
# Steps to do this interactively, I'd like a non-interactive version.
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
GTK_DEBUG=interactive mate-calc

# Then go to `MathWindow → GtkBox → GtkMenuBar`
# click on the (i) icon to show the details view
# `allocation` indicates the `width×height+x+y`, here it's `312×25+0+0`
```

Solutions I've considered:

- Use xdotool to control the GTKInspector automatically (expect poor performance + the need to have an extra GTKInspector window on the side).
- Use dbus, but `d-feet` does not show the widget tree and I suspect the things it shows about `interface` are about OOP or the d-bus interface, not about some *user* interface.
- Back in the good old days, we could do similar things with `dcop` for QT applications, but of course it won't work for GTK.

Answer (score 4):

`dogtail` uses assistive technologies to access an application's widget tree. Tested on Xubuntu 20.04.

```
$ sudo apt install python3-dogtail
$ sniff # explore using a GUI, it will enable assistive technologies for you.
```

`dogtail-example.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from dogtail.tree import *
app = root.application('mate-calc')
menuBar = app.findChildren(predicate.GenericPredicate(roleName="menu bar"))[0]
print('On-screen coordinates: ', menuBar.position)
print('Size:                  ', menuBar.size)
# to preview the nodes available in the menu bar, use menuBar.dump()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 dogtail-example.py
On-screen coordinates: (529, 431)
Size:                  (312, 25)
```

There are a few examples in `/usr/share/doc/python3-dogtail/examples/` but the actual "doc" is in the docstrings of `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dogtail/tree.py` and other files in that directory.